# Finding unordered sequence of values in an ordered List/Array/Buffer

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to create a game in Java. I want to create a feature where you can sacrifice items, and if you sacrifice the right 'recipe' of different items, you get something in return. A pseudo example of recipes could be:

```
recipe1[1, 5, 32]
recipe2[4, 221, 21, 9]
```

The *order* of the recipes should not matter - meaning, if I have 
`input = ..., 7, 5, 32, 1` this should return *true* for `recipe1[1, 5, 32]` - but the *sequence* should matter, so `input = ..., 5, 7, 32, 1` returns *false*, even though input does contain all the values of recipe1.

I have no real code yet, as I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Two questions: how many recipies and how big is the input sequence? What do you need to optimize: e.g. fast lookups of new recipies for a static input sequence?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut 
 
The number of recipes is potentially infinite (but they will not be dynamically created, so there'll always be a static number of recipes), and the size of the input sequence should probably be the size of the longest recipe. I'm thinking of using something like CircularFifoQueue for the input sequence. I want it to be optimized for fast lookup of static recipes in an unpredictable, dynamic, ordered input sequence (hope I'm getting my terminology right here, I'm kindof a self-taught novice programmer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would be much easier to implement if you use a Set of Sets.

```
Set<Set<Integer>> recipes = new HashSet<>();
```

now you can check if a recipe is part of the set:

```
boolean contains = recipes.contains(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,5,32));
```

The order is not important, but the exact items are.

---

Ah, I think I misunderstood, this is the exact opposite of what you are asking for. Dang!

Looking for the items in the right order will perform a lot worse and be more tedious. Basically, you can do a [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List%2C%2520T%29) for the first item in the sequence. And if you find it, keep looking from there. Your data structure would be a List in that case.

---

No, I think it's closer to my initial understanding after all. Use the set of sets, but test it for all possible sub-lists of your input.

Comment: At this point, wouldn't it be better to use a `containsAll` call and pass in the collection that you're comparing it to?

Comment: How does this help with the sequencing constraint?

Comment: @wadda_wadda nope, you want to find a single item in the outer set, and you want an exact match in the inner set

Comment: @ThomasJungblut one recipe would go in one set. As I understood the OP, he wants to match the recipe items, independent of order. If order is important, change inner from Set to List

Comment: So you would need to fill the inner lists with the permutations of the whole input sequence? Doesn't seem like a very efficient solution.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I think I misunderstood the OP :-(. Added clarification.

Comment: i think your initial understanding was correct. The exact items in a recipe is important, but the order is not.

Comment: @MikkelRavnholtSimonsen then you have your solution

Comment: Hmmm, only partly, I don't need to check whether a recipe is part of my collection of recipes, I need to know if some kind of ordered collection (what I refer to as `input` in my OP) contains one of my recipes - this ordered collection could be a LinkedList, an array, CircularFifoQueue etc. I have a hard time imagining this being possible without iterating.

Comment: you will definitely have to iterate over all possible sublists, yes